# If $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$, $Y_n$ to $Y$, $X_n, Y_n$ and $X, Y$ pairwise independent then $X_n+Y_n$'s distribution converges to $X+Y$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Suppose that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$, $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$. Suppose that, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Prove that $X_n + Y_n$ converges to $X+Y$ in distribution.

Here is a hint that was given:

First prove that $\bigcup_n\{(X_n, Y_n)\} \cup (X,Y)$ is tight, then use the following theorem, which we can assume is true:

Theorem: Let $S$ be any metric space. Let $N \subset C_b(S)$ be a subset of the set of all countinuous and bounded functions on $\mathbb R$, satisfying the following properties: for all $\epsilon > 0, f \in C_b(S),$, and $K < \infty$, there exists $g \in N$ such that $|g(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [-K, K]$ and $\sup_{x \in S} |f(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in S} |g(x)|$. Assume furthermore that we have distribution functions $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ that are tight.

Then $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if, for all $g \in N$, $\int g\  d\mu_n \to \int g \ d\mu$.

Following the hint, we know that $\mathbb P((X_n, Y_n) \leq (x,y))$ = $\mathbb P(X_n \leq x, Y_n \leq y) = \mathbb P(X_n \leq x) \mathbb P(Y_n \leq y)$ so that, given $\epsilon > 0$ we may choose big enough $M$ such that both $\mathbb P(|X_n| \geq M)$ and $\mathbb P(|Y_n| \geq M)$ are bigger than $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, so that the tightness of the distributions follows.

The problem here is choosing the appropriate $N$ that satisfies the requirements of the theorem. An example of $N$ that satisfies the requirement of the theorem are $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, the set of all smooth functions on $\mathbb R$ with a compact support. Another hint is that we should choose $N$ as a subset of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

I am kinda stuck. Could anyone help? Also, is my proof that $\bigcup_n\{(X_n, Y_n)\} \cup (X,Y)$ is tight correct?

Comment: This is easy using characteristic functions (assuming $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued).

Answer (score 1):

By Levy's Theorem, it suffices that for each $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$,
$\int e^{i\theta(X_{n}+Y_{n})}dP\rightarrow\int e^{i\theta(X+Y)}dP$.
Since $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ and $Y_{n}\rightarrow Y$ in distribution,
we have that $\int e^{i\theta X_{n}}dP\rightarrow\int e^{i\theta X}dP$
and $\int e^{i\theta Y_{n}}dP\rightarrow\int e^{i\theta Y}dP$. Since
$X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are independent, we also have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int e^{i\theta(X_{n}+Y_{n})}dP\\
 & = & \int e^{i\theta X_{n}}\cdot e^{i\theta Y_{n}}dP\\
 & = & \int e^{i\theta X_{n}}dP\cdot\int e^{i\theta Y_{n}}dP\\
 & \rightarrow & \int e^{i\theta X}dP\cdot\int e^{i\theta Y}dP\\
 & = & \int e^{i\theta(X+Y)}dP,
\end{eqnarray*}
where the last equality follows from the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are
independent. QED

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering if you could confirm that my proof that $(X_n, Y_n)$ is tight is correct as well?